# List array deseralization with JavaScriptSerializer() fails

Tags: c#, json, list, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have a JavaScriptSerializer() that deserialize a JSON from a web service and fails on runtime due to a wrong handling of a list.

This is my class:

```
public class LoginReply
{
    public Userdata userdata { get; set; }
    public List<string> errors { get; set; }
}

public class Userdata
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string section{ get; set; }
    public string avatar { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string authkey { get; set; }
}
```

And I deserilize with:

```
LoginReply reply = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<LoginReply>(loginRespose);
```

I also tried with:

```
LoginReply reply = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<LoginReply>>(loginRespose);
```

without any success

> (Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'Redacted.Redacted.LoginReply')

Comment: Post the received JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem relies in here:

```
LoginReply reply = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<LoginReply>>(loginRespose);
```

Youa re trying to deserialize the loginRespose to a list of LoginReply but in other side you are declaring it not as a list.

For the first attemp we have to see the json assigned to loginRespose variable because it might be null or not valid json or does not have the properties like `LoginReply` class.

If the json is coming like a list of `LoginReplys` you might have to tro deserializing it to a list of this class like below:

```
List<LoginReply> reply = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<LoginReply>>(loginRespose);
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess no more programming at 3AM for me